# Send password by email to User

Tags: laravel

I would like to know if it's a good practice in terms of security to send the decrypted password to a new user by email. Someone could tell me his feeling?

If i would like to send the password decrypted should i use this ?

```
$decrypt= Crypt::decrypt($user->password);
```

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Why do you want to send decrypted password to **new user** ?

Comment: This has already been answered here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17979/is-sending-password-to-user-email-secure

Comment: because it's not the user itself who get registered , so i try to find an easy way to inform to him his connection acces

Comment: @MathieuMourareau Once they register, send them a link to create a password. This would be more secure. Apart from that password must be hash.

Comment: The ability to decrypt passwords is bad practice to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You can't decrypt hashed password. The good practice is to use Laravel resetting password feature.

> Once you have defined the routes and views to reset your user's passwords, you may simply access the route in your browser at `/password/reset`. The `ForgotPasswordController` included with the framework already includes the logic to send the password reset link e-mails, while the `ResetPasswordController` includes the logic to reset user passwords.
>
> After a password is reset, the user will automatically be logged into the application and redirected to `/home`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passwords

Answer (score 0):

**Based on the comments:**

Once user is register send him/her a link to create a new password.

If you don't want to allow them to access other pages until they create a new password. Add the `middleware` to check whether user has create a new password or not.

From view point of security, password must be hashed value. You shouldn't use encryption/decryption for password.

Comment: thanks for your reply ! wish route should i put inside the email ? reset password ?